# Order by using pivot table

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
       datename(month, [date]) as [Month],
       planttype, 
       (sum(noof50kgsbags * 50))[Total Kgs]  
    FROM
       K_FP_Indent 
    WHERE 
       (date BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND getdate()) 
       AND (attrited = 'True') 
    GROUP BY 
       datename(month, [date]), month([date]), planttype,[date]) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM([Total Kgs])
    FOR [planttype] IN (A,B,C,D)
) AS s2
```

How to use order by statement to this query? I know that we cannot use order by for inline queries

**Output:**

```
Month   A       B         C      D
April   x       X         X      X
August  X       X         X      X
July    X       X         X      X
```

**Desired OP**

```
Month   A       B         C      D
April   x       X         X      X
July    X       X         X      X
August  X       X         X      X
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      planttype CHAR(1)
    , [Date] DATETIME
    , noof50kgsbags FLOAT
    , attrited VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (planttype, [Date], noof50kgsbags, attrited)
VALUES 
    ('a', '20130401', 5, 'True'),
    ('b', '20130801', 5, 'True'),
    ('c', '20130701', 7, 'True')

SELECT s2.[Month], a, b, c, d
FROM
(
    SELECT
          [Month] = DATENAME(MONTH, [Date]) 
        , mt = MONTH([Date])
        , planttype
        , [Total Kgs] = SUM(noof50kgsbags * 50) 
    FROM @temp
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND GETDATE()
        AND attrited = 'True'
    GROUP BY
          DATENAME(MONTH, [Date])
        , MONTH([Date])
        , planttype
) s
PIVOT
(
    SUM([Total Kgs])
    FOR [planttype] IN (a, b, c, D)
) s2
ORDER BY mt
```

**Output:**

```
Month     a      b       c       d
--------- ------ ------- ------- -------
April     250    NULL    NULL    NULL
July      NULL   NULL    350     NULL
August    NULL   250     NULL    NULL
```

**Update:** *How can i use order by clause to inline queries*

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT --<--
          [Month] = DATENAME(MONTH, [Date]) 
        , planttype
        , [Total Kgs] = SUM(noof50kgsbags * 50) 
    FROM @temp
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND GETDATE()
        AND attrited = 'True'
    GROUP BY
          DATENAME(MONTH, [Date])
        , MONTH([Date])
        , planttype
    ORDER BY MONTH([Date])
) s
PIVOT
(
    SUM([Total Kgs])
    FOR [planttype] IN (a, b, c, D)
) s2
```

Comment: It shows an error like "The multi-part identifier "s.Month" could not be bound."

Comment: Please give me a few minutes :)

Comment: @ajmalmhd04 - `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.`

Comment: @Bhagavan - you can't/shouldn't. Only an `ORDER BY` on the outermost query is guaranteed to work. the `TOP 100 PERCENT` fudge shown in the second query here may not produce the results you expect.

Comment: Fully agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @Devart  Using top with percent producing op but not in the order

Comment: @Bhagavan I know about that. I added last query only for example.